# How to communicate between the viewmodel and model if model is in separate project in WPF client application?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I am new to WPF and Entity Framework. I am planning to follow MVVM pattern in a WPF client application and Entity Framework for model. For security reasons I don't want to include the entity framework reference in the client application. I have the following query on this front.

In the above case which is the best way to communicate between viewmodel and model?

Answer (score 1):

Well if you really want to separate the application layers that hard, you could create a `WCF Service`, which loads the entities from the data source and passes it to the client.

You can find some information on creating a `WCF Service` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734712.aspx). For information about consuming such services you should have a look [here](http://www.devproconnections.com/article/net-framework2/How-to-Consume-a-WCF-Service-Using-WPF-124992). But you will find many articles in the WWW.

Comment: Hi..Thanks for the quick response. But at the same time I am supposed to support UI changes(object state change i.e by modifying a value in UI) to track back to the database. How to support this?

Comment: Well you could implement a `DirtyFlag` in the base class of your VMs. With it you can determine which entities have to be written to the DB. Btw, I don't believe, that you want to store every modification. I think this mechanism should be more sophisticated. Think on rollbacks of the last edit operations. You could implement `IEditableObject` for this purpose.